# SQL Server, new job fails

Tags: visual-studio, history, jobs, ssis-2012, sql-agent

I have SQL Server 2012, and I create an SSIS package for upsert data in table, and it works when I execute it in Visual Studio 2012.

When I try to create a new job (it's the first time that I do it) and I start the job it fails, and in the history of the job I have the following errors :

> Executed as user: NTCH01_SQLAgent2012. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5583.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  16:21:24  Error: 2016-08-24 16:21:24.85
>   Code: 0xC0202009
>   Source: Load data to staging table OLE DB Destination [132]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2016-08-24 16:21:24.85
>   Code: 0xC020901C
>   Source: Load data to staging table OLE DB Destination [132]
>
> Description: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[BANK_GUARANTEE_EXPIRY_DATE] on OLE DB Destination.
>   Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2016-08-24 16:21:24.85
>   Code: 0xC0209029
>   Source: Load data to staging table OLE DB Destination [132]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2016-08-24 16:21:24.85
>   Code: 0xC0047022
>   Source: Load data to staging table SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.
>   The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (132) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (145).
>
> The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>
> Started:  16:21:24  Finished: 16:21:24  Elapsed:  0.842 seconds.
>   The package execution failed. The step failed.

I don't understand the meaning of the error

Could you help me please ?

Comment: "Invalid character value for cast specification" says it cannot convert the data from one data type to another then couple that with the next error which is saying data would be lost if the input that is mapped to Bank_gaurantee_Expiry_date inserts the value.  So it looks like you have a conversion issue, perhaps a date in the input isn't really a date?

Comment: @Matt , you are right , it's a date, but it's not the only field with date, so I don't know what's wrong with it, beside that I execute it in Visual studio and it works ... what should I change , Thanks sir

Comment: I had a derived column for DTDATE, and I was not mapping the good output, now it works perfectly . thank you